# Grub menu not showing everytime

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I am using Windows 11. Recently for my needs, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in my laptop alongside Windows 11. It was working fine. But I saw updated 22.04 LTS version. So, I downloaded this version and updated it with bootbale USB.But there was some issues like wifi problem. I was getting slow wifi. So, I delete the disk of Ubuntu from Windows 11 then used bootable USB to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS again. But after deleting and running , a grub was shown with error.

`Minimal BASH like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.`

I somehow managed to get back and install Ubuntu. Then grub menu was not showing. I searched for solution and somehow solved it. But then after installing grub doesn't show every time. I have to use F9 those times and update grub using this command: `sudo update-grub`. Well, I don't need to edit grub config file. timeout and grub option seems okay as they are save as 10 and menu type.

Now how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Your motherboard BIOS has to be set to boot to Ubuntu first.

Comment: Can you tell us what make/model of laptop you have and we might be able to help set your UEFI boot parameters. I doubt that a laptop running Windoze 11 has a BIOS.

Comment: I'm using HP Pavilion 15-eg1678TU.

Comment: I was facing problem to set Ubuntu first. I was changing ubuntu to first but it automatically changed to windows.

Comment: How are you changing Ubuntu to first? HP does not seem to acknowledge changes with efibootmgr which grub uses during install. HP typically needs UEFI update & change of boot order in UEFI settings, not in UEFI boot menu.